# FB doesn't redirect back to site...stays on blank page

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the example code from the Facebook C# SDK...specifically the CS-AspNetWebForms-JsSdk project as a basis...and I've essentially copied the Facebook>Logon.asxp and Facebook>Default.aspx to my project, which is a C# DotNetNuke module. I then saved them as user controls. Besides that, I have not made any changes to the code itself...(except some of the using statements, etc to get it to build in the DNN environment).

When I run the baseline sample code provided in the Facebook C# SDK, it runs fine. But when I run the version within DNN, I am having a problem with the oAuth popup window (called from Javascript) that doesn't close and redirect back to my site. It just stays open without any content displayed (a blank white page).

Here is the first URL that is displayed in the popup browser window right after I click the FB Login button:

```
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=270792352985332&skip_api_login=1&display=popup&cancel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D3%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%26error%3Daccess_denied%26error_description%3DThe%2Buser%2Bdenied%2Byour%2Brequest.%23cb%3Df282f9d6e4%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Ff3ce290c44%26relation%3Dopener%26transport%3Dpostmessage%26frame%3Dfc708cc48&fbconnect=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Fpermissions.request%3F_path%3Dpermissions.request%26app_id%3D270792352985332%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fs-static.ak.fbcdn.net%252Fconnect%252Fxd_proxy.php%253Fversion%253D3%2523cb%253Df282f9d6e4%2526origin%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25252Ff3ce290c44%2526relation%253Dopener%2526transport%253Dpostmessage%2526frame%253Dfc708cc48%26sdk%3Djoey%26display%3Dpopup%26response_type%3Dtoken%252Csigned_request%26fbconnect%3D1%26perms%3Duser_about_me%252Cpublish_stream%26from_login%3D1&rcount=1
```

If I use a fresh user (one that hasn't approved the app and is not even logged in), the FB login page shows, then the permissions page...so far, so good. But when it comes time to redirect back to my site...no luck. The oAuth browser window open just sits there, with a blank page. Here is the URL in that window at that time:

```
https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php?version=3#cb=f282f9d6e4&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ff3ce290c44&relation=opener&transport=postmessage&frame=fc708cc48&access_token=AAAD2SMIB8PQBAPE7Jx46Nf4aPZAeqd0iM9TibKsZAx7NajjR3U6AWomEMrX6QsplRhWNoOfuhh7wLEWCT5zQYzbYBW3DGYN7uEdS0tOqg8vXKzTQvI&expires_in=3727&signed_request=8PpxwfwmImbBT9DVjIZ5CzdtMHHu449k0OYQAoP627A.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImNvZGUiOiJBUUNsMm5OcE1vZWFuNXlOd2I0UUp6UjEyNU5mWTdJRl9VOGw0ZlZFZzI0MlhyM0Q4ZU8ycTdkdFJMc1RpbktiRUczY2JCeHBiMVNqLTdBQWtFc3NJSlUyZ0VnV2dtZHhsN21aMmUydnU4ZGNJUnJmLXdKeXdzVGl5WFpIVjA4TTJwOVNLOEZUdlFEVkhtUE15dkhOei1zOXB3MjIxVlZsQXJjZDZ1QzNLV0kwM2NFaG1UU1JjQzU4WkxIanRRZXlMYjI2MnhUd2w0azRkLXFneTEzQUZGN3IiLCJpc3N1ZWRfYXQiOjEzMjY0Nzc0NzMsInVzZXJfaWQiOiIxMDAwMDMzMzk2NDAxNjUifQ
```

Here is my code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Logon.ascx.cs"        Inherits="Incite.Modules.MySitterGetter.Logon" %>

<%--<input type="button" id="fblogin" value="Login to Facebook" disabled="disabled"/>--%>
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" 
Text="Please click the button below to login to Facebook."></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:ImageButton ID="fblogin" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/DesktopModules/Incite/MySitterGetter/images/fb_login_button.jpg" Enabled="True" />
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '<%: Facebook.FacebookApplication.Current.AppId %>',
            channelUrl: '<%: FBChannelURL %>', // Channel File
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true
        });

        function facebooklogin() {
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {    
                    // user authorized
                    window.location.reload();
                } else {
                    // user cancelled
                }
            }, { scope: '<%: string.Join(",", ExtendedPermissions) %>' });
        };

        $(function () {
            // make the button is only enabled after the facebook js sdk has been loaded.
            //$('#fblogin').attr('disabled', false).click(facebooklogin);

            $('#' + '<%= fblogin.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', false).click(facebooklogin);

        });
    };
    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());
</script>
```

And the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using DotNetNuke;
using DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities;
using DotNetNuke.Security;
using DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions;
using DotNetNuke.Services.Localization;
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules;
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.Actions;

using Facebook.Web;

namespace Incite.Modules.MySitterGetter
{
public partial class Logon : PortalModuleBase
{
    protected string[] ExtendedPermissions = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["extendedPermissions"].Split(',');
    protected string FBChannelURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fbChannelURL"];

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthorized(ExtendedPermissions))
        {
            if (Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("ReturnUrl"))
            {
                var returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];

                // prevent open redirection attacks
                if (IsUrlLocalToHost(Request, returnUrl))
                {
                    //Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
                    return;
                }
            }

            //Redirect to this page after login
            //Response.Redirect("~/");
            lblMessage.Text = "Successfully logged into Facebook!";
            Response.Redirect("~/FBAccount.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Facebook login FAILED!";
        }
    }

    public static bool IsUrlLocalToHost(HttpRequest request, string url)
    {
        // http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/preventing-open-redirection-attacks
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
        {
            return false;
        }

        Uri absoluteUri;
        if (Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out absoluteUri))
        {
            return String.Equals(request.Url.Host, absoluteUri.Host,
                        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }
        else
        {
            bool isLocal = !url.StartsWith("http:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                && !url.StartsWith("https:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                && Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.Relative);
            return isLocal;
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Note this happens in Firefox, Chrome, and IE9, which is all I have. 
Also, if I navigate back to my login page (with the Logon.ascx contro) TWICE....without re-clicking the FB login button, it then passes the if (FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthorized(ExtendedPermissions)) check. So even though the redirect isn't happening, it is authorizing.

Sorry for the long post.
Any help is GREATLY appreciated as I've wasted nearly a day on this so far!

Chad

Comment: Ok, I forgot I did make one other minor change from the orignal sample code in the SDK. I changed the Login button to an image button (so it would look nicer and use the Facebook login image (more recognizable to the users). This....for some reason that is beyond me...causes this problem. You can see in my .ascx file the original button commented out and a new image button inserted, and then the line of code in the jquery to only enable the button once the sdk loads to accommodate the server side control ID naming. But I tested it 3 times. This was the problem. Any idea why??? TIA.